# dropdown fix for ie

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, internet-explorer-8

In IE the dropdown list is coming upward inspite of coming downward when you click on it because of more number of values in it. In mozilla its working fine. Any suggestions? how to bring it downward. Also i am using IE8.

```
<s:select theme="simple" key="" id="" value="12" list="#{'1':'1','2':'2','3':'3'
,'4':'4','5':'5','6':'6','7':'7','8':'8','9':'9','10':'10','11':'11','12':'12','13':'13','14':'14','15':'15','16':'16','17':'17','18':'18','19':'19','20':'20','21':'21','22':'22','23':'23','24':'24','25':'25','26':'26','27':'27','28':'28','29':'29','30':'30','31':'31','32':'32','33':'33','34':'34','35':'35','36':'36'}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean upward when it has no room to open fully downwards? Hence if you scroll the list be to near the top of the page, it works fine?

Comment: yes dropdown is in the lower part of the page so it has not much room to display the values downward. Thats why it is populating the values upward. Scrolling works fine, i just need to scroll for starting values like 1,2 and so.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is something that seems to be handled by the browser explicitly, even after your html/javascript code.

Meaning that if IE detects that's it's a `select` and has the ability to make it an *updrop* due to little space, it will.

Alternatively you can use a custom dropdown control which will not actually render as a `select`, therefor you will have more control on how it works. There are many that can be found on-line using JavaScript/jQuery.

Personally I think it might be too much trouble for such a feature.